# Condense Excel embed CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, excel

This may be a stupid question so, I will apologize in advance, if so.  If you look at my working example here http://www.realtimehockey.net/associations.html within my tabbed content, I intend to have a total of 6 Excel spreadsheets in the content area under each tab.  I am saving my spreadsheets as a web page and integrating the source code into my site.  Problem is that the resulting CSS/HTML code is excruciatingly long.  For 6 separate spreadsheets, it seems as if the code never ends.  Is there a way to possibly condense this code without affecting any of the "performance"?  Or perhaps another solution.  I've tried using Excel Online, however, this produces an iframe, which would be great but, it doesn't allow for the addition of images(social icons).  Any input would be greatly appreciated.  I'd love to post my code, however, the amount of characters drastically exceeds the allowed characters here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the embed code from the Excel file and include it in a separate HTML file. Then you put six separate iFrames for each of the Excel embed files in the tabs with the desired width/height. This will preserve your ability to have the social icons and keeps your main `HTML` file more clean and uncluttered. It does create additional HTTP requests, but "performance" will not be significantly decreased.

```
<iframe src="excel-tab-1.html" width="300" height="300">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Comment: thanks very much for the assistance.  I figured it may be an easy fix.  I appreciate.

Comment: You're welcome. There are better ways to do it, "performance"-wise, but this will work with what you have already set up. Happy coding!

Comment: Again thanks for your assistance, however, I'm having a bit of a problem trying to figure out exactly how to do this.  I'm new to coding so, when you say "include in a separate HTML file", how do I go upon that?  And I will be grabbing the iframe from Excel Online, correct?  Sorry to be a pain.  Just not having much luck figuring this out.

Comment: @DavidLytle Maybe this example will help. Check out the source of this example I created (link below). You'll have six HTML files that hold just the content for the iFrame, and then embed one iFrame for each file into your page in the `#tab-content` divs. http://cjo.me/so/29787281.html

Comment: I'll give this a shot.  I guess I'm just not sure where I am getting the iframe content("excel-tab-1.html above).  I've tried the source from my spreadsheet but got no results.  In viewing your example, it did not show me the source code.  When I clicked, it just eliminated the frame.  Sorry for my naivety.